# Multiple Input - One output Neural Network in small dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

The dataset i am working on has 7 input features and 4 output class. The length of my dataset is 160. Will neural network be a good choice here? If so, how should i take my inputs to the neural network. Since I have 4 output class, i am going to use Softmax in the final layer. 
If neural network makes no sense in such a small dataset, then what are the possible good Machine Learning Algorithms for have a great result in this kind of problems?.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of a dataset do you have? I am assuming a tabular dataset.

You can use a neural network if you must. However, for such a small dataset, a neural network isn't usually advisable. You should rather look into the following classifiers:

1. Decision Tree
2. Naive Bayes
3. Multi-class Logistic Regression
4. Support Vector Machine
5. Ensemble models (Random Forest and/or Gradient Boosting)

Comment: Thanks. yes, it's tabular data.

Comment: Look into this to get you jump started: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html